# Teamcity - multiple docker registries credentials

Tags: docker, teamcity

I need to build docker image with my Dockerfile and then push it to our private docker registry. The problem is that in the Dockerfile we have:

`FROM docker_image_on_docker_hub`

so TC needs to store and use credentials for docker hub access. But
once the build is done the image needs to be pushed to our private docker registry.

I know I can do that using `Command Line` runner with script where I can run `docker login ...` but ... is it possible to do that using just Build Features, Connections (anything else) ?

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the version of TeamCity you are using, anything after TC 2017 should be good, support for logging into container registries is available.

Steps:

1)Go to any Project's Settings page.

2)Click on "Connections" in the menu sidebar.

3)Click + Add Connection -> Select Docker Registry and fill in the required fields.

4)Go to Build Configuration Settings (a build from the same project)

5) Build Features -> + Build Feature -> Docker Support and select your connection

Assuming you entered everything in correctly, any build with that connection as a Build Feature will be logged in before the build starts.

If your version does not have this feature, you can always make a Command Line build step inside an empty Build Configuration and select Export Meta-Runner from the Actions dropdown. This will combine the build's current Build Steps into one Custom Build Step that will always be available as an option to select from in future Build Configurations. The key is to create the Command Line steps in a way that is re-usable with parameters that automatically become Form Fields when exported into a meta-runner.

Comment: I am using the latest available TC. I did it all but if failed. It didn't know what connection should be used for each build step.

Comment: awesome! I was building CI pipeline in teamcity and adding build feature worked for me. thanks

Comment: From my experience, the Docker Support Build Feature is buggy: From time to time (but not always!) my docker registry responds with HTTP-401 when tring to upload a new image. Concurrent builds from different projects seem to interfer with each other. Thus I will `docker login`and `docker logout` in separate, dedicated build steps. I'm on TeamCity Enterprise 2019.2.2 (build 71923).